# How to force log out after session expired?

Tags: javascript

Currently if the session token is expired, there's no way for the application to know. We have to wait until they make any request after that to know their session has timed out, and redirect them to login again. Is there a way to check for the expiration in the background, and if the token is expired, force them out immediately? I was thinking about setTimeout, but could not really come up with an implementation yet.

Answer (score 3):

To check your token is expired or not you have to make call to backend. and if you make several api calls using setTimeout that could create performance issues and bad practice.
so i suggest you should use sockets. Backend will fire an event when current session is expired and when you receive that event logout the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set the session timeout to 30 minutes
const SESSION_TIMEOUT = 30 * 60 * 1000;

let timeoutId;

function startSessionTimeout() {
  // Clear any existing timeout
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);

  // Set a new timeout to log the user out
  timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    // Log the user out
    logout();
  }, SESSION_TIMEOUT);
}

function resetSessionTimeout() {
  // Reset the timeout when the user makes a request
}
```